# Groovy - get subkeys in map

Tags: java, dictionary, groovy, hashmap

I have the following `Map` :

```
errors:[[context:null, message:A restriction with the matcher ID refs/heads/devel already exists, exceptionName:com.atlassian.stash.internal.hooks.permissions.DuplicateRestrictedRefException]]
```

Lets say that the object name is `mappedJson` how can i check if the `exceptionName` key exists in the `errors`

I've tried

Comment: `mappedJson.errors*.exceptionName`?

Comment: It will return to me a list even if the `exceptionName` doesn't exist, the list will look like this: `[null]` , but it's not helping me. Is there any boolean function?

Comment: `boolean exists = mappedJson.errors*.exceptionName.any()`?

Comment: Thanks , I'll try it